# Quero editar um contrato em pdf usando PHP, ou JS, ou qualquer solução web que sirva

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerenciamento para uma empresa, lá eles possuem vários contratos para diversos serviços. Eu já tenho os contratos em mãos e já sei onde o meu sistema vai ter que alterar neles (os lugares específicos) mas como eu faço isso via PHP, ou JS ou qualquer outra solução web ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar desenvolver o modelo do PDF em HTML, para depois salva-lo para PDF.

Existe um pluguin para o editor wysiwyg [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud) que converte o html para um pdf

https://www.api2pdf.com/tinymce-save-to-pdf-plugin/

Este é um exemplo básico de como usa-lo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            external_plugins:
                {
                    'saveToPdf': 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/Api2Pdf/api2pdf.tinymce/master/save-to-pdf/dist/save-to-pdf/plugin.js'
                },
            toolbar: 'saveToPdf',
            saveToPdfHandler: '/REPLACE-WITH-HANDLER-URL'
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>Testing saveToPdf</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muitissimo Obrigado Erlon, ajudou bastante mesmo.